# react native gradient button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-native

I have a problem with my btn component, I am using react-native-linear-gradient lib...

**btn.js**

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import {View,Text,StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {Button,Item} from 'native-base';

import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

class GradientBtn extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
    return(     
        <LinearGradient colors={['#d7d7d7', '#fafafa', '#e8e8e8']} 
        style={[styles.btnContainer,{height:this.props.h,width:this.props.w}]}>
            <Text style={styles.btn}>{this.props.name}</Text>
        </LinearGradient>





    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    btnContainer:{
        backgroundColor:'#f0f0f0',
        justifyContent:'center',
        marginLeft:1
    },
    btn:{
        textAlign:'center',
        color:'#000',
        fontWeight:'700',
        fontSize:12
    }
});

export default GradientBtn;
```

**app.js**

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-between',marginTop:5}}>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <GradientBtn h={35} w={'24.55%'} name="Open Corrective"/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <GradientBtn h={35} w={'24.55%'} name="Open Corrective"/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <GradientBtn h={35} w={'24.55%'} name="Open Corrective"/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <GradientBtn h={35} w={'24.55%'} name="Open Corrective"/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

when I remove TouchableOpacity tag from component then the view will ok, but I want touch opacity on that btn when I placed this tag then my view will compress means out the width and didn't see proper btn..

Comment: you might want to try using `flex: 1` on `TouchableOpacity`

also, for reference, here's my component library for this: https://github.com/thomaswangio/react-native-gradient-buttons

Answer (score 3):

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linear-gradient

```
<LinearGradient colors={['#FF00FF', '#FFF000', '#FF0000']}
    style={{borderRadius: 20, width: width/3}} 
    start={{ y: 0.0, x: 0.0 }} end={{ y: 0.0, x: 1.0 }}>

    <Button style={{borderRadius: 20, width: width/3, 
        textAlign: 'center', color: '#fff'}} title={`Welcome`}/>

</LinearGradient>
```

or

```
<LinearGradient colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']} 
    style={styles.linearGradient} 
    start={{ y: 0.0, x: 0.0 }} end={{ y: 0.0, x: 1.0 }}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Done </Text>
 </LinearGradient>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  linearGradient: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 15
    paddingRight: 15,
    borderRadius: 5
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'Gill Sans',
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: '#ffffff',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
const GradientBtn = ({ name }) => (
   <LinearGradient colors={['#d7d7d7', '#fafafa', '#e8e8e8']} style={styles.gradient}>
      <Text style={styles.btn}>{name}</Text>
   </LinearGradient>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gradient: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

& apply `width` & `height` to the `TouchableOpacity` itself

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.wrapper}>
  <GradientBtn name="Login" />
</TouchableOpacity>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    width: '24.55%', 
    height: 35
  }
});
```

Didn't try it though but I guess it will work :)